# Error in OnTouchEvent()

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the different gestures in android.The text of the textView2 will be changed depending upon which gesture have been called but I am getting an error in the last method OnTouchEvent().Please help.Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends
AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener ,  
GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

private TextView t;
private GestureDetectorCompat gd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    this.gd=new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
    gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    t.setText("on down");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    t.setText("on Fling");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    t.setText("on long press");

}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    t.setText("on show press");
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    t.setText("on scroll");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    t.setText("on single tap");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    t.setText("on double tap");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    t.setText("on double tap event");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    t.setText("on single tap confirmed");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: can not resolve gestureDetector

Comment: There's no gestureDetector field in your class, hence compilation fails.

Comment: I am new to Android can you please explain in more detail or fix that error for me. I will be grateful to you